# Why the form is invalid at FormView?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

All fields are filled. But for some reason does not go into the `form_valid` method, but it goes into `form_invalid`. Why form is invalid?

**forms.py**

```
class CreditFilterForm(forms.Form):
    CURRENCY_CHOICES = (
        ('KZT', _('KZT')),
        ('USD', _('USD')),
    )

    PERIOD_CHOICES = (
        ('1', _('One year')),
        ('2', _('Two')),
        ('3', _('Three'))
    )

    sum = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id': "sum", 'class':"forminput-text"}))
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CURRENCY_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'name': "minbeds", 'id':"currency"}))
    term = forms.ChoiceField(choices = PERIOD_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id':"term", 'name': "minbeds"}))
```

**views.py**

```
class CreditsList(ListView):
    model = Credit
    template_name = 'credits/credit_listing.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        little_form = CreditFilterForm(self.request.GET or None, prefix="little")
        ...

class LittleForm(FormView):
    form_class = CreditFilterForm
```

**template**

```
<form action="{% url 'little_form' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ little_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="{{ little_form.prefix }}" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I think you did not use the `prefix`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prefix` is applied to *all* form input widgets. But in your `LittleForm` view, you did not use that prefix.

You can add it by overriding the [**`prefix`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.prefix):

```
class LittleForm(FormView):
    form_class = CreditFilterForm
    prefix = 'little'
```

> **Note**: I advice to rename `LittleForm` to `LittleFormView`. It makes it more clear what that class is, and it will avoid a "collision" if you later construct a form with the same name.